# How to win a war in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

I've attacked all their Resource-Stations, Hovered a planet (In hope to blockade/bombard it - but it didn't), what am I missing?

The score remains 10% of war goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To win a war you need to get your war score high enough to a point where the enemy will either surrender and agree to the war goals you specified or you can negotiate depending on high your war score.

To gain war score you can do the following:

- Invade a planet - You can bombard a planet, which as you described is what you did but after you've worn down the enemy army and defenses you need to deploy your land armies to invade the planet it conquer it. To do this you recruit the armies, deploy them into space and land them on the target planet. Be warned there is a large amount of fortifications on most planets so it's best to bombard first. If you conquer a planet, this is usually the planet that will be given away during a war/negotiations.
- Win a fleet battle - By engaging in a battle with an enemy fleet and winning you gain war score. I believe this is calculated depending on the size of fleet you destroy, as noted by @Raven Dreamer fighting and even destroying enemy ships does not generate warscore if either you or the enemy retreats.

These two methods will increase war score, however it would be a good strategy to destroy space stations and blockade planets to prevent valuable resources being given to your enemy, when blockading it will stop any tile resources from reaching the enemy without the need to conquer the planet. 
[Wiki with information](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Warfare)

Comment: 10x, how does blockade works? do I just need to hover the planet? I wasn't given any options when I pointed the fleet toward the wanted planet.

Comment: @ShloEmi Once you enter orbit around a hostile planet, your ships will start bombardment. Click on the planet and go to the 'Armies' tab. Here, you can see the current fortification levels, choose which level of bombardment you want, and see what effects that level will have. Higher levels of bombardment shut down production on the planet. I assume this is what Wessels meant by "blockade".

Comment: You can *only* get planets that were declared as part of your goals at the end of a war, even if you occupy others, but you *must* occupy your goal planets in order to get them, even if you have enough war score to cause a surrender.

Comment: @DCShannon It is possible for you to acquire planets you don't occupy iff your enemy totally capitulates. If you "negotiate" using your war score, you're correct, however.

Comment: Do note that fighting and even destroying enemy ships does not generate warscore if either you or the enemy retreats.

Comment: @DCShannon - Take a look at the wiki (http://www.stellariswiki.com/Warfare#Blockade) it provides information on what a blockade does but I do specify in my post. Blockaded planets will not send resources to home faction but doesn't not require a ground army to take over the resource buildings. It's a quick way to stop resources from reaching the enemy.

Comment: @ShloEmi Blockades work by just orbiting the enemy planet with a fleet, the idea is they will block ships leaving the planet to deliver resources, I think. Steam thread shows how to start a blockade. https://steamcommunity.com/app/281990/discussions/0/357286033301021293/

Comment: @RavenDreamer With regards to your information on taking planets not specified in the war goal, it is possible. The enemy can throw in different planets in a attempt to en hostilities, I tested this for myself and they will offer planets you have successfully invaded, but not ones from a war goal (unless invaded aswell), this doesn't apply if you attempt to negotiate as you cannot demand planets not specified in the wargoal, but enemies can offer other planets to end the war. Wiki specifies here: http://www.stellariswiki.com/Warfare#Declaring_War

Comment: There are somewhat contradictory statements in that wiki. It agrees with the tutorial when it says that "Even if your enemy capitulates in the war, you will only get what you specified as war goals", but then goes on to say that "However, your opponent may offer you a different planet that you are occupying in the interests of ending the war."

Comment: @DCShannon My understanding of that is the enemy will cede a planet that you have captured in the interest of ending the war, as opposed to fully surrendering and submitting to your war goal demands. The difference being if they offer you a planet that you have captured, you will not get the planets specified in your war goal, if win the war and they agree to your war goal demands, you will obtain all planets specified in the war goal, but nothing else.